# Is there a way to listen to the upload events in the EMC's Documentum via .NET API?

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc

i need to implement a windows service that connects to EMC's Documentum and receives an event every time a document is loaded. 
The event should contain the reference to the document itself. 
Is there a way to do it via API or do i have to do polling using a web service?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest would be to implement this via polling.

Your Windows service can either

- access DFS exposed service (that you need implement on DCTM side)
- access docbase directly using DFC/.NET

But the question here is what is that you want to check? 
Document loaded - If you are referring to dm_document object created (e.g. by a user/system or some sort of upload functionality) - you will need to register dm_audittrail for that event. Once that is in place your service or API call can check for dm_audittrail entries.

Alternatively you could use Documentum BOF (Business Object Framework) to write custom code that would be triggered every time for instance new document is being crated (or updated) - i.e. on specific predefined event.
This custom code could do whatever you like, like for instance broadcast JMS message to a queue that your Windows Service is listening. You see to implement the thing that you want (event based notification) you need some communication channel between your application and a content server.

Or simply just poll Docbase it every x seconds.

Guess you already know this but a lot of info can be found on:
https://community.emc.com/community/edn

Also BOF Guide (older version): https://developer-content.emc.com/developer/downloads/BusinessObjectsDevelopersGuide.pdf

Comment: Tnx a lot for the reply. I don't have much experience on the framework of Documentum. The second option would work for me, but I have to understand if i need to change or not the behavior of the solution implemented by the customer. The user requirements do not include changes effectively to the solution released in the production environment.... can i do this? can i use Documentum BOF outside the solution?  Regards

Comment: if by release solution you are referring to Documentum installation /application then yes. You would need to change it  - even more if the client already has BOF implementation (i.e. Type Based Objects) you would need to amend existing code base.

The only way not to 'touch' client installation is to write custom (simple DFC) client that will poll Docbase

I've edited original answer with reference to BOF Developers manual (older version but the concepts are the same)
 
Hope this helps

Comment: I have to investigate with the customer if I can make changes in a "painless" way to the existing solution. I hope to receive the support needed by the technicians who do maintenance on the instance of Documentum. Otherwise it will develop a solution through polling. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Rest Service. Documentum whole functionality exposed in rest service. https://community.emc.com/community/labs/archivedprojects/dctm_rest

Comment: Tnx, i hope to find the better solution soon